# fcitx5 bamboo doesn't work with Texmaker and Viber on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, latex, input-method, fcitx

I'm running Arch Linux with Kernel x86_64 Linux 6.7.2, I installed Texmaker 5.1.4-2 which is a official package on Arch, and I also installed fcitx5, fcitx5-bamboo, and the whole bunch of fcitx5 package.

Thing went well with any apps on my system including Microsoft Teams, Lark Suite, Chromium, Brave, but not Texmaker. It seems that fcitx5 can not detect the input environment in Texmaker.

I tried to change the input method, switch back to English and between languages but nothing worked. I tried to log out or restart and nothing happen. Even when the Vietnamese input method is on, and Texmaker window opened but nothing happens.

[image]

It doesn't work with Viber 21.8.0.11-1 as well.

So how can I fix that? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: This is a problem with Viber bundling some libraries that don't work with fcitx. This workaround https://gist.github.com/vinhjaxt/498b1348069cf047e121641c79777c6b worked for me a few years ago, now it does not.